# Closing a xxforms:dialog which contains a xbl datatable generates an unknown error

Tags: orbeon

Using 4.0.0 Beta 3.

We have a dialog using xxforms:dialog which is opened using xxforms:show and closed using xxforms:hide (either from an action button or the X (close) button). There is a common thread that if the dialog contains a xbl datatable an unknown error is generated (See below).

Sometimes the dialog hides completely with no client side error, other times the dialog does not re-render the page because a client side error occurs ( Message: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tooltips[control.id].cfg.getProperty') )

Any thoughts?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|[No error message provided.]                                                                                          |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException                                                                            |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.BindingContext$$anonfun$ances|apply                         |BindingContext.scala          |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.BindingContext$$anonfun$ances|apply                         |BindingContext.scala          |  71|
|scala.Option                                       |getOrElse                     |Option.scala                  | 108|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.BindingContext               |ancestorOrSelfInScope$1       |BindingContext.scala          |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.BindingContext               |pushVariable                  |BindingContext.scala          |  74|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContextStack           |scopeVariable                 |XFormsContextStack.java       | 224|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsActionAc|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  48|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsActionAc|apply                         |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  41|
|scala.collection.Iterator$class                    |foreach                       |Iterator.scala                | 772|
|scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper  |foreach                       |JavaConversions.scala         | 573|
|scala.collection.IterableLike$class                |foreach                       |IterableLike.scala            |  73|
|scala.collection.JavaConversions$JListWrapper      |foreach                       |JavaConversions.scala         | 615|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsActionAc|execute                       |XFormsActionAction.scala      |  41|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterprete|runSingleIteration            |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 204|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterprete|runAction                     |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 150|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException          |wrapException                 |ValidationException.java      | 126|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterprete|runAction                     |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 157|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonf|apply$mcV$sp                  |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 249|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonf|apply                         |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 249|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.EventHandlerImpl$$anonf|apply                         |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 249|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.DynamicVariable                |withValue                     |DynamicVariable.scala         |  40|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |withScalaAction               |XFormsAPI.scala               |  39|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.EventHandlerImpl       |handleEvent                   |EventHandlerImpl.scala        | 248|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                |  79|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  43|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withDebug                     |Dispatch.scala                |  22|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  78|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
|scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfu|apply                         |TraversableLike.scala         | 697|
|scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class          |foreach                       |LinearSeqOptimized.scala      |  59|
|scala.collection.immutable.List                    |foreach                       |List.scala                    |  76|
|scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter        |map                           |TraversableLike.scala         | 696|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              | 116|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 722|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 305|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 225|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 169|
|org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase|invoke                        |AuthenticatorBase.java        | 472|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 168|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         |  98|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve          |invoke                        |AccessLogValve.java           | 927|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve           |invoke                        |RemoteIpValve.java            | 680|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 118|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 407|
|org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor   |process                       |AbstractHttp11Processor.java  | 999|
|org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnecti|process                       |AbstractProtocol.java         | 565|
|org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProces|run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 309|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor            |runWorker                     |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       |1110|
|java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |run                           |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 603|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 722|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
```

Comment: Could you create a standalone simple example that reproduces this? Then we can have a look at it, but if it is a bug, I can't guarantee we'll fix it, as the datatable isn't currently very high on our priority list.

Comment: Here is a simple standalone example to run in the sandbox. click on the enable dialog, click on the open data table, select an entry by clicking on the row, then click on the X to close the dialog box.  https://github.com/jeflam/TestSnippets/blob/master/datatable-issue-01.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for the reproducible test case. I created a bug (see my answer below), but can't guarantee we'll be able to take care of this for you soon. In the meantime, do you have a workaround? Would you be able to not use the datatable? At this point, the datatable isn't actively maintained, and I would recommend against using it, if you can.

Comment: The datatable are intrinsic to the solution and we do not want to re-invent the wheel by using repeats and css. However, I have investigated this further and it appears that the problem may reside in the dialog hide mechanism. If we use close="false" and build in a custom X close trigger in the top right hand corner of the dialog box. Within the trigger action we add a forms:delete to remove the instance that is used in the data table. Add same delete to just before any xxforms:hide, and the error does not occur.

Comment: xxforms-dialog-close does not work as this appears to execute after the internal closures of xxforms:hide. Thus we believe that the dialog hiding mechanism is not removing the instance bindings correctly?? -

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a bug. I created an [issue for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/828) on GitHub, and you can watch that thread if you'd like to get updates on this.